# Passing a model to different Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass a model to a View called List but List is in a different folder called Results

```
public ViewResult SmokingEnvironments(Screen model)
{
    return View("List", model);
}
```

Comment: The framework won't know to look there by default. Look into areas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: consider putting view in a `/Views/Shared` folder view engine does check that folder. It sounds like you have a case of shared view here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
public ViewResult SmokingEnvironments(Screen model)
{
    return View("/Views/Results/List.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: The view 'Results/List' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Results/List.aspx
~/Views/Home/Results/List.ascx

Comment: @user2224493 Try with `return View("/Views/Results/List.cshtml");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
return View("../Results/List", model)
```

This worked for me. ../ is for moving up one if you are in some other controller.